# How can I see all users of domain in this PC?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, windows-server-2003, active-directory, windows-domain

If I do:

```
whoami /groups
```

I can see all the groups I belong.
My current user e.g. **X** belongs in a domain (there is a Domain Controller)
My question is why if I go to `Control Panel>Manage Accounts` I can **not** see X as a user?
I only see local admin.
It has administrator priviges in the AD of the Domain Controller, though.

Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 3):

Domain users cannot be managed or seen from the Manage Accounts screen, however you can see them in the Computer Manager => Users and Groups area. To manage them, you have to be logged on to the domain controller and use the Active Directory manager or alternatively use the Remote Management tools for Windows Server.

To view AD users with accounts on the local machine:

- Open Start
- Go to Control Panel
- Click on Administrate Tools
- Click on Computer Management
- Click on Local Users and Groups
- Click on Users

Comment: Domain accounts will not show up in the "Local Users and Groups/Users" of a client computer, as it's for holding "local" users (not domain users). :)  Domain accounts that belong to local groups, WILL show up in local groups though.

Answer (score 1):

To get a list of AD users from a Windows PC belonging to AD:

1. Right click on a file and select Properties.
2. On the Security tab, click the Edit button
3. Click the Add button. Set these fields:

   1. Object Types=Users
   2. From this location: `<your AD domain name>`
4. Click the Advanced button
5. Configure your query (Name, Starts with etc) and results columns (you might want Alias or LogonName etc)
6. Click the Find Now button

[image: Screen capture of the Properties, Permissions, and Select Users dialogs]

Comment: You may want to add extra columns like Alias or Logon Name.